# Substring function that is like the PHP function?

Tags: coldfusion, substring

is there a function like PHPs substring? I saw Left and Mid but those all make me specify the length of what I want the string to be.

Here is PHP's function example:
$rest = substr("abcdef", 1);    // returns "b"

I just want to be able to take a string and start it at a certain point, not end it as well.

Comment: Wouldn't substr("abcdef", 1); return "bcdef"?

Comment: I don't know php, but according to the docs I looked up, substr('abcdef', 1); returns 'bcdef': http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php So, it acts just like CF's Mid().  Could be wrong, tho

Comment: @Edward M Smith - Not exactly the same.  Mid has the count parameter.  With PHP's substr, you don't need to tell it how many characters to grab.

Comment: @mbeckish yes my bad. The thing is I do not want to have to specify the length. I only want to start it at a certain point, not also have to say where it ends. Isn't there some function?

Comment: @Darren - You could use REReplace, and specify a regular expression to strip off the first n characters.  However, I think it would be easier to just use Mid, and use Len to calculate Mid's count parameter.

Comment: Ah, suggest you edit the question to fix the example (// returns 'bcdef') for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since CF strings are java strings, you can use java string functions

```
<cfset foo="abcdef">
<cfoutput>#foo.substring(1)#</cfoutput>

returns: 'bcdef'
```

Or, if you don't like that, you could do (not elegant, but functional):

```
mid(foo,2,len(foo))
```

Comment: I do not see what is wrong with using the latter example. If you do go with the java substring(), be sure to understand its differences from CF's MID function (0-based index, inclusive/exclusive index, etcetera..)

Answer (score 1):

From [substring in coldfusion](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=343174):

Try

```
Left(string, length) //returns number of characters defined by length
```

or

```
Mid(string, start, count) //returns the set of characters from string, beginning at start, of length count.
```

Comment: Please read the question. You have to specify a length in these, which sucks, and there should be a function in ColdFusion where you don't have to.

Comment: I would like to change many aspects of many languages / frameworks, but sometimes you have to work with what you have. Just trying to help, man...

Answer (score 0):

[CFLib.org](http://cflib.org) is the awesomest collection of user-defined functions.

There is a UDF that does exactly what you want: [SubStr](http://cflib.org/udf/SubStr)

> It mimics the behaviour of php
>   "substr", enclosing mid, left and
>   right functionalities into a single
>   function and adding some
>   extra-functionality and trick. For
>   instance: - substr("abcdef", -2) is
>   the same as right("abcdef", 2), -
>   substr("abcdef", 1, 3) is the same as
>   left("abcdef", 3), - substr("abcdef",
>   2, 4) is the same as mid("abcdef", 2,
>   4) At the same time, it permits things
>   like - substr("abcdef", 2) instead of
>   mid("abcdef", 2, len("abcdef")-2) -
>   substr("abcdef", -2, 1) to say "start
>   2 chars before the end of the string,
>   and take 1 char." - substr("abcdef",
>   -4, -1) to say "start 4 chars before the end of the string, and throw away
>   the last char." It returns an empty
>   string in case of inconsistent
>   indexes.

Here's the source:

```
<cfscript>
/**
* Returns the substring of a string. It mimics the behaviour of the homonymous php function so it permits negative indexes too.
*
* @param buf      The string to parse. (Required)
* @param start      The start position index. If negative, counts from the right side. (Required)
* @param length      Number of characters to return. If not passed, returns from start to end (if positive start value). (Optional)
* @return Returns a string.
* @author Rudi Roselli Pettazzi (rhodion@tiscalinet.it)
* @version 2, July 2, 2002
*/
function SubStr(buf, start) {
// third argument (optional)
var length = 0;
var sz = 0;

sz = len(buf);

if (arrayLen(arguments) EQ 2) {

        if (start GT 0) {
         length = sz;
        } else if (start LT 0) {
         length = sz + start;
         start = 1;
        }

} else {

        length = Arguments[3];
        if (start GT 0) {
         if (length LT 0) length = 1+sz+length-start;
        } else if (start LT 0) {
         if (length LT 0) length = length-start;
         start = 1+sz+start;

        }
}

if (isNumeric(start) AND isNumeric(length) AND start GT 0 AND length GT 0) return mid(buf, start, length);
else return "";
}
</cfscript>
```